# Is there an alternative to whiptail for macOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

I would like to try out a shell script that makes use of [whiptail](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail), but I am on a MAC and whiptail doesn't seem to exist there. Does anyone know if there exists a drop-in alternative (like, for example [exa](https://github.com/ogham/exa) for [ls](https://ss64.com/osx/ls.html))?

This is the script I would like to test out (It's a [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) script that would allow me to select local WordPress installs, using a dialog. Found it at the bottom of [this page](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/references/shell-friends/)):

```
#!/bin/bash

WP_TOP_PATH="/home/"
MENU_TEXT="Choose an installation"
GAUGE_TEXT="Searching for WordPress"

declare -a MENU
WPS="$(wp --allow-root find "$WP_TOP_PATH" --field=version_path)"
WP_TOTAL="$(wc -l <<< "$WPS")"
WP_COUNT="0"

while read -r WP; do
    WP_LOCAL="${WP%wp-includes/version.php}"

    NAME="$(cd "$WP_LOCAL"; sudo -u "$(stat . -c %U)" -- wp --no-debug --quiet option get blogname)"
    if [ -z "$NAME" ]; then
        NAME="(unknown)"
    fi
    MENU+=( "$WP_LOCAL" "$NAME" )

    echo "$((++WP_COUNT * 100 / WP_TOTAL))".
done <<< "$WPS" > >(whiptail --gauge "$GAUGE_TEXT" 7 74 0)

WP_LOCAL="$(whiptail --title "WordPress" --menu "$MENU_TEXT"  $((${#MENU[*]} / 2 + 7)) 74 10 "${MENU[@]}" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)"

if [ $? -ne 0 ] || [ ! -d "$WP_LOCAL" ]; then
    echo "Cannot find '${WP_LOCAL}'" 1>&2
    exit 100
fi

echo "cd ${WP_LOCAL}"
```

Comment: Though I don't know much about bash, this feels very much like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get whiptail on macOS by installing newt `brew install newt`

reference: https://command-not-found.com/whiptail

Comment: should definitely be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

I would start with `brew install dialog` from https://brew.sh and then

```
alias whiptail=dialog
```

Hopefully you don’t have to alter your script other than dropping the alias as a new line 3 in your script. For people not already using Wordpress on other Unix, the Apple specific apps and installers seem like a great option as well due to [extensive documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP) and [native apps](https://apps.wordpress.com/desktop/).

- https://wordpress.org/download/

Lastly, if you find you need whiptail, containers are a great option so you don’t have to fork your tools and edit scripts.

- https://localwp.com/

Comment: It probably will require either a symlink (`ln -s $(brew --prefix)/dialog /usr/local/bin/whiptail`) or changes in the script. Aliases usually are ignored in scripts.

Comment: Agreed @nohillside I did not load up that script to test things thoroughly - I figure if the OP gets bash, it’s a non issue and if they don’t the other suggestions are more durable than getting them to the next roadblock using bash to manage Wordpress local installs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the [answer of bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/434135/90654) and the comment from @nohillside I was able to make this work. After running `brew install dialog`, I put this in my `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
alias whiptail=dialog
```

And to make my script actually respect the alias, I followed the [instructions found here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1498/504158) and put this in my script at the very beginning:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s expand_aliases
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Great to see that it works. Relying on an entry in .bashrc makes this non-portable though. To be on the safe side, it probably would make more sense to define the alias directly in the script (instead of sourcing .bashrc). Or even use a shell function :-)

Comment: Awesome answer. I got stuck between a function and an alias. I might even just change my answer to use a variable for the binary if you want another option.